# Even or odd. If the number is equal to 0, the program must stop

Tags: java

I need to write for each number the sequence output `even` if the number is even, otherwise, `odd`. If the number is equal to `0`, the program must stop reading and processing numbers.

```
Input 
1
2
3
0
Output
odd
even
odd
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num;
        for (; ; ) {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            num = reader.nextInt();
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("even");
            }
            else if(num == 0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("odd");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem with your code.

Comment: Your problem is that you're checking `num % 2 == 0` first. Do that *after* you check if it's `0`

Comment: You should apply the check for `num == 0` first. Otherwise, whenever the number is even, `num%2 == 0` passes and the code won't stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your posted code is addressed in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139586/even-or-odd-if-the-number-is-equal-to-0-the-program-must-stop#comment109900651_62139586) (*checking `num % 2 == 0` first*), but in this case we can improve upon your solution. First, it's "idiomatic" in Java<sup>1</sup> to use a `while` loop with a test after assignment. Second, it's possible to use a [`?:` conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) (a ternary) and remove the remaining `if` / `else`. Like,

```
int num;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
while ((num = reader.nextInt()) != 0) {
    System.out.println(num % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
}
```

<sup>1<sub>I don't know who defines idioms, but I didn't invent it. And I've seen this construct in JDK source.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
int num;
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
for ( ; ; ) {
    num = reader.nextInt();
    if (num == 0) {
        break;
    } else if (num % 2== 0) {
        System.out.println("even");
    } else {
        System.out.println("odd");
    }
}
```

Your problem is the sequence of your `if/else` conditions. If the first input is `0`, `0 % 2` returns `true` - so it will never `break`.

Also, you do not need a new `Scanner` every time. You can take it out of the loop and reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the value is zero before checking if the value is even.
For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;

    while(true) {
        num = reader.nextInt();

        if(num == 0) break;
        else if(num % 2 == 0) System.out.println("even");
        else System.out.println("odd");
    }
}
```